# Excel VBA loop with loop running a certain number of times based on cell input

Tags: excel, loops, variables

I am trying to run this macro a set number of times based on a cell value and then copy and paste the results though I need to actively change the paste location offsetting down by 1 row per number of iterations so the first time it pastes results at this cell and the second time one row lower etc...here is the code - any help would be great.  thanks

```
Range("AQ2:AU2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("AS255:AW255").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Calculate
```

I have updated to this

```
For x = 1 to ActeiveCells("A1").value
y=255
Range("AQ2:AU2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("AS" & y &:":AW" & Y).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
y = y +1
Calculate
```

Every time the macro calculates the cells AQ2:AU2 get different numbers and I want to run 100 loops and get all those results and paste in the cells from AS & Y:AW & Y and then stop after how many time I say in cell A1

Ok lets start from beginning I did not do a good job of explaining this is the original code

```
Calculate
  Range("AQ2:AU2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AS255:AW255").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Calculate
Range("AQ2:AU2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("AS256:AW256").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,
```

I just kept changing the cells I was pasting to and then recalculating i did this for 100 iterations and it works - though it is sloppy and not efficient  my goal is to loop this 100 or maybe 500 times with the results after calculating to be copied from cell AQ2:AU2 _ these cells never change to the cells AS : AW but the row changes so i keep the previous results

Comment: Have you attempted to create this loop on your own?

Comment: sorry - I have done it manually with a variable

Comment: dim looped for looped = 1 to 100   I want to do the loop a set number of times based a cell value

Comment: It is not a good idea to use copy and paste in VBA.  It is slow and error prone.  Simply use a = b and it should do the same trick like VBA Pete is showing you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How how about a **FOR Loop** with an **IF Statement**:

```
Sub CopyCode()

    y = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "AS").End(xlUp).Row +1

    For x = 2 To 100 'change to however often you would like to run the code

         'Trigger for MC simulation would go here
         Range("AS" & y & ":AW" & y).Value = Range("AQ2:AU2").Value
         y = y + 1

    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: I did the loop part by using

Comment: for x = 1 to ActiveSheet.Cells("a1")

Comment: now I need to change the paste section to move down so the range ("AS255:AW255") needs to offset based on the loop count.  I am pasting all the iterations of the calculation in different cells to compare reuslts

Comment: that's what the code does. Starts at ("AS255:AW255") , then goes to ("AS256:AW256"), ("AS257:AW257")  and so on...

Comment: Ok - but the number of iterations is dependent on the cell value so if Cell A1 = 100 then the loop would run 100 times and then end.  The data is changed every time the calaculate is performed.

Comment: That was not clear from your question. You can count for the last value and add your new values after that.

Comment: agreed - i pasted the orgianl code shortned it to 2 iterations as i had 100

Comment: Ok, I think I understood now what you are after. Just updated the code, even though I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with the final code.

Comment: it's a Monte Carlo simulation using random number generation in excel.  So every time the spreadsheet calculates a simulation is run and random numbers are generated. The results are in in aq2:au2.  Then we save the simulation results in as255:aw255 and re run the simulation and save results in next cells down.

Comment: I see. I added to the code where you would put the trigger for MC simulation. Let me know if the code works for you.

Comment: Thanks.  This is perfect.  Though I changed the top back to your original thought of y=255.   Thanks again!!!!

Comment: @MJR No worries. Don't forget to tick the answer box if you liked my answer.